# Cannot save NSURL objects from ALAsset into a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, alassetslibrary, alasset

I try to retrieve all URLs of the videos from the Camera Roll and save the `NSURL` objects into a `NSMutableArray`. As you can see in the code I also print the URLs in the console to see, if they are not empty/nil. Therefore, I am using following method:

```
- (void)buildCameraRollLibrary{

    camerRollList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    UIImage *viewImage;

    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);


        }
    }];


    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll  usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){

        if (group != NULL) {

            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){


                if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo]) {
                    //NSLog(@"asset: %@", result);

                    ALAssetRepresentation* defaultRepresentation = [result defaultRepresentation];
                    NSURL *url = [defaultRepresentation url];
                    NSLog(@"%@",url);
                    [camerRollList addObject:url];
                }

            }];
        }

    }
                         failureBlock:^(NSError *error){

                             NSLog(@"failure"); }];
}
```

My problem here is, that I can see the proper URLs of all my videos in the console, BUT if I add them into my `cameraRollList` `NSMutableArray`, then this Array is empty.

Does anyone has a suggestion how I can solve this issue? And for information, I want to use this URLs to play the videos in a `AVPlayer`.

Thank you in advance!

Attached you can see the output of my console:

```
2013-11-08 22:09:41.629 SwiPlayer[621:60b] assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=5D39F2FA-E161-450C-AC6F-27348754112A&ext=MOV
2013-11-08 22:09:41.648 SwiPlayer[621:60b] assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=DD7925FA-9F06-403D-ACBA-13A9C7B6E1AF&ext=MOV
2013-11-08 22:09:41.664 SwiPlayer[621:60b] assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=B277D0E9-E6CA-44FA-9365-72E3BCDA2156&ext=mov
2013-11-08 22:09:41.667 SwiPlayer[621:60b] assets-library://asset/asset.mp4?id=7929B692-EEA3-4918-B63F-DB77B13A8499&ext=mp4
2013-11-08 22:09:41.669 SwiPlayer[621:60b] assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=32B60AA6-D46D-40B3-A97F-6980A999D048&ext=MOV
2013-11-08 22:09:41.686 SwiPlayer[621:60b] assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=45FCEC33-A158-4794-B9DB-C70E8A828F35&ext=MOV
2013-11-08 22:09:41.694 SwiPlayer[621:60b] assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=3157C207-7649-4E0F-A8E2-943C3C95298F&ext=MOV
2013-11-08 22:09:41.697 SwiPlayer[621:60b] assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=6B043E7C-4399-4376-8B1B-51DDF3DD79DD&ext=MOV
2013-11-08 22:09:41.762 SwiPlayer[621:60b] url (null)
```